# Getting current request page size

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I need to get current page request size which could be set by an input field named `limit`. I can get this when it's newly set using `getParam('limit')` on current request object. But later it seems its value is stored somewhere in the session so I'll miss it. I read about `getPageSize()` but I don't think it would be helpful here.

What is the best suitable way to get current page size limit?

[image]

Comment: On which version? M1 or M2?

Comment: @SukumarGorai It's v1.9.

Comment: On which file you want?

Comment: @SukumarGorai Does it matter? I'm going to have it in an observer within a customized module.

Comment: I think not. Check my answer this will return you the current page size of current product collection

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get limit on any page:

```
<?php $toolbar = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar; ?>
<?php echo $toolbar->getLimit(); ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This actually returns `12` which I think is the default value in an xml file.

Comment: Yes. and if you change the the limit then its also updating. I have checked the same code in my footer and tested.

Comment: I'm changing it by selecting a number in that drop down list (20,30,50,...) but it always returns `12`. However there is no `12` in list.

Comment: Can you clean the cache once. Also can you try to add the above code to your footer.phtml for testing?

Comment: It shouldn't differ but I did clean the cache now. The output is the same. It's `12`. I'm printing this value directly into the page, somewhere that it `die`d within observer method.

Comment: Can you try once in private browser? Because its working fine

Comment: If this method works only if cache is disabled then really I shouldn't use it. And, no it doesn't output something different. I doubt if it depends on cache. It's a literal value that comes from a configuration file, I think.